# SQL, counting on the same table, multiple partition types

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, sum

I'm trying to query a table that shares many Entity Types (Ticket, TicketNote, TimeEntry, Resource, etc.).
When I run multiple inner joins, the counts always return the same data.
The query I've designed below works but is it the best way to be doing this?

```sql
select 
    ticket.data ->> 'TicketNumber',
    ticket.data ->> 'Title',
    count(case when entry.name='TicketNote' then 1 end) notes,
    count(case when entry.name='TimeEntry' then 1 end) times,
    sum(case when entry.name='TimeEntry' then (entry.data ->> 'HoursToBill')::numeric else 0 end) hours_to_bill
from caches ticket
inner join caches entry
on (entry.data ->> 'TicketID')::numeric = ticket.aid and (entry.name = 'TimeEntry' or entry.name = 'TicketNote')
where 
    ticket.name = 'Ticket'
group by ticket.data
order by hours_to_bill desc;
```

I'm rather green in SQL.

I appreciate any wisdom.

Thank you!

Comment: What does those `->>` mean? Method invocation?

Comment: `->>` is a jsonb operator [jsonb docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) "Get JSON object field as text"

Comment: Alright, I see. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
select ticket.data ->> 'TicketNumber' as ticketNumber,
       ticket.data ->> 'Title' as title,
       count(*) filter (where entry.name = 'TicketNote') as notes,
       count(*) filter (where entry.name = 'TimeEntry') as times,
       sum((entry.data ->> 'HoursToBill')::numeric) filter (where entry.name = 'TimeEntry') as hours_to_bill
from caches ticket inner join
     caches entry
     on (entry.data ->> 'TicketID')::numeric = ticket.aid and
        (entry.name = 'TimeEntry' or entry.name = 'TicketNote')
where ticket.name = 'Ticket'
group by ticketnumber, title
order by hours_to_bill desc;
```

This is really just tweaks on your query.  It uses the more modern `filter` syntax -- which can be a bit more efficient sometime.  And it is more explicit about the aggregation criteria.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely unaware of this syntax. I'll also take note of how you fixed my whitespace formatting.